# Combining various xml elements into one collection using GML/C#/LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, gml

I am attempting to read a GML file in C#.  I would like to store all the returned data in one object.  So far I have been able to return all the data but in 3 separate objects:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
XNamespace gml = "http://www.opengis.net/gml";

// Points
var points = doc.Descendants(gml + "Point")
              .Select(e => new
              {
                POSLIST = (string)e.Element(gml + "pos")
              });

// LineString
var lineStrings = doc.Descendants(gml + "LineString")
                  .Select(e => new
                  {
                      POSLIST = (string)e.Element(gml + "posList")
                  });

// Polygon
var polygons = doc.Descendants(gml + "LinearRing")
               .Select(e => new
               {
                   POSLIST = (string)e.Element(gml + "posList")
               });
```

I would like to instead of creating 3 separate objects, I would like to create one object as follows:

```
var all = doc.Descendants(gml + "Point")
          doc.Descendants(gml + "LineString")
          doc.Descendants(gml + "LinearRing")....
```

But need some help.  Thanks before hand.

Sample Data:

```
<gml:Point>
<gml:pos>1 2 3</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
<gml:LineString>
<gml:posList>1 2 3</gml:posList>
</gml:LineString>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:posList>1 2 3</gml:posList>
</gml:LinearRing>
```

Comment: Gilad, I have added sample data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Concat`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
XNamespace gml = "http://www.opengis.net/gml";
var all = doc.Descendants(gml + "Point")
             .Concat(doc.Descendants(gml + "LineString"))
             .Concat(doc.Descendants(gml + "LinearRing"));
```

For getting the values as the inner elements you can do something like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
XNamespace gml = "http://www.opengis.net/gml";
var all = doc.Descendants(gml + "Point")
             .Select(e => new { Type = e.Name, Value = (string)e.Element(gml + "pos") })
             .Concat(doc.Descendants(gml + "LineString")
                        .Select(e => new { Type = e.Name, Value = (string)e.Element(gml + "posList") }))
             .Concat(doc.Descendants(gml + "LinearRing")
                        .Select(e => new { Type = e.Name, Value = (string)e.Element(gml + "posList") }));
```

Comment: @Robert Smith - Check this

Comment: Thanks Gilad!  How would I select "pos" for points and "posList" for LineString/Polygons as you see in my above example?

Comment: @RobertSmith - Does it now do how you need?

Comment: It is perfect, even better than perfect since you added the "Type = e.Name" i was going to need!  Thank you very much!

Comment: @RobertSmith - Also look in the documentation link that I gave you - always a good place to start from :) Upvoting good examples there is also good

Comment: @RobertSmith - Glad it helped you

Comment: Thanks again, I will take a look at the documentation.